# Show a div by wrap with another controller doesn't work

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-controller

I have a button in a div with a controller named `controllerBubble`. I would like this button show a div controlled by an other controller : `controllerDependance`. Is it possible to wrap the button in a div and the hidden div with same controller but it doesn't works.
This is my HTML :

```
<div ng-app="app">

  <div ng-controller="mainController" ng-show="myvalue" class="ng-cloak">
    <div id="panelSap" ng-controller="controllerDependance">
      My hidden div
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="containerDetailsTicket" class="clearfix" ng-controller="controllerBubble">
    Div which contains the button
    <div id="containerButton" ng-controller="mainController">
      <button ng-click="showAlert()">Afficher</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

This is my controllers :

```
var d3DemoApp = angular.module('app', [])
d3DemoApp.controller('controllerBubble', function() {

});

d3DemoApp.controller('controllerDependance', function($scope) {
  $scope.myvalue = false;
  $scope.showAlert = function() {
    $scope.myvalue = true;
  };
});

d3DemoApp.controller('mainController', function AppCtrl($rootScope, $scope) {
  $scope.myvalue = false;
  $scope.showAlert = function() {
    $scope.myvalue = true;
  };
});
```

I created a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/z1ORNRzHbr7EVQfqHn6z?p=preview) 
Any idea what's happening ? Someone can do work on the Plunker. I Hope someone can help me.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look, not sure why you want to have such a nesting of controllers but **I am pretty much sure that it ain't good**. I'll tell you why. In your code, you are trying to use same controller at two DOM ele. So, **they are having 2 different scope** `$scope` and so they are not working.

I have made a [working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/UCMj4MdADw0GxCNo6CH2?p=preview) for you by using `$rootScope`but its not a clean approach as you'll be having a *global variable* (`$rootScope.myvalue`) declared. Declaring global variable should always be avoided unless forced to.

Another [suggested approach in plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/4IQifcCroGqEn7UcWIYp?p=preview) is to use `$emit` as event notifier. The `$on` would take appropriate action when the event is triggered. You can even pass values that too to different controllers.

Service can also be used to pass values among `controller`s .

Let me know if you need more info

> Update 1:

If you want to remove some `div` (not hide) then you should try to use `ng-if`.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response, how to do if I want to remove a div when click on same button. I create another ng-show but if I put a ng-show, the div is already hidden, can you check the Plunker ? https://plnkr.co/edit/YR2L2ltluvVT3yJqRxii?p=preview Thanks a lot !

Comment: @afeffifari-1957: Your english is not clear enough for me to understand your approach.  :(  I've updated the answer from what I understood from your comment.